# How to be notified when frame in absolute coordinates change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I need to be notified when my custom UIView subclass's absolute frame (not only frame relative to its parent, but also when superview's/grandsuperview's etc. frames change, causing my view's frame to change) changes on screen. I've tried getting the absolute frame `convertRect:toView:` at `-(void)didMoveToSuperview`, `-(void)didMoveToWindow` and I've also added this code inside both:

```
UIView *view = self.superview;
while (view) {
    [view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"superview" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    view = view.superview;
}
```

They are all called a few times (which is okay), but I'm getting incorrect coordinates. There's something else that runs *after* all of those code which sets the actual visible frame. I verify this by putting this in my code:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGRect globalFrame = [view.superview.superview convertRect:view.superview.frame toView:[[view.delegate tutorialView] superview]];
        NSLog(@"after 2 sec %@", NSStringFromCGRect(globalFrame));
        if([view.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(attachedViewFrameDidChange:)]){
            [view.delegate attachedViewFrameDidChange:globalFrame];
        }
    });
```

Forget about `view.delegate` and my other custom parameters/objects/methods. After two seconds, I am getting the correct value in `globalFrame`. I have the exact same code in `-(void)didMoveToSuperview`, `-(void)didMoveToWindow`, `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context` and they all get called with incorrect frame values (getting an incorrect value when I call `convertRect:toView:`. Why can this be, and how can I get the absolute/true frame value (the one I see on the screen) as I get after two seconds, obviously without waiting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by making your custom view a delegate of the view controller, and calling a delegate method in viewDidLayoutSubviews. So, in the view controller.h, I had this,

```
@protocol UIViewControllerLayoutChanged <NSObject>
-(void)layoutChanged;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<UIViewControllerLayoutChanged> delegate;
@end
```

In the .m file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setDelegate:(RDLabel *)self.label]; // self.label is the view I want to be notified when its absolute frame changes
}


-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [self.delegate layoutChanged];
}
```

In my custom view class,

```
-(void)layoutChanged {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect([self.superview convertRect:self.frame toView:nil]));
}
```

This gave me the correct absolute frame whenever I changed it. Of course, viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called any time any view needs to be laid out again even if it doesn't involve the view you care about. To handle this you might need to keep a reference to the frame in your custom class's code, and only do whatever you need to do if its frame changes from the old value.

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution, however, I'm developing the code for a 3rd party library, and I can't access the controller of the view. Even if I find the view controller in view hierarchy by checking next responders, I don't want to "inject" code into it via the means of swizzling or categories (I can't subclass the controller). It'd be really nice if I could have a solution that doesn't involve view controllers.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, well then, what do you have access to?

Comment: The view itself, and its superviews. Only "custom class" that I have in hand is the view itself though. Its superviews can be anything.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, are the observer methods called every time that the frame of your view or one of its superviews changes its frame. In my testing, I didn't see that.

Comment: They are called twice for keypath "frame" in my example.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, that's strange. I copied your code, and if I move my view's superview, I don't get the observer being called (the window, and the controller's main view do call the observer on rotation).

Comment: My code resides in a complicated project, maybe that's why it gets called at different times. However, the initial problem still applies.